# Unable to Show/Hide span spinner through Javascript & AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show and hide a spinner on a submit button of a contact form. While the form is being submitted the spinner should be showed on the button. As soon as the form gets submitted the spinner should be hidden.

Here's my submit button along with the spinner span:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn btn-medium btn-fancy btn-primary mb-0 ls-wider" type="submit" id="submitButton">
    <span class="submitSpinner spinner-border spinner-border-sm me-1"></span> Send Message
  </button>
</div>
```

And this is the AJAX function I'm using:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.submitSpinner').css('display','none');
        $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#submitButton').text('Sending Message');
          $('.submitSpinner').css('display','inline-block');
          var data = {
            'name': $('#name').val(),
            'email': $('#email').val(),
            'phone': $('#phone').val(),
            'company': $('#company').val(),
            'message': $('#message').val(),
          }
          $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/contact/message/send",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
              // console.log(response);
              if (response.status == 400) {
                $.each(response.errors, function(key, error) {
                  $('#contact-alerts').append('<div class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-7 alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in show" role="alert"><button type="button" class="btn-close line-height-unset" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>' + error + '</div>')
                });
                $('.submitSpinner').css('display','none');
              } else {
                $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
                $('#submitButton').text('Send Message');
                $('.submitSpinner').css('display','none');
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                  showCloseBtn: true,
                  items: {
                    src: '#contact-success'
                  },
                  type: 'inline',
                  fixedContentPos: false,
                  fixedBgPos: true,
                  overflowY: 'auto',
                  closeBtnInside: true,
                  preloader: false,
                  midClick: true,
                  removalDelay: 300,
                  blackbg: true,
                  mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom',
                });
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: is the `display` being set to `none` and can you see the spinner if you set the `display` to just `inline-block` without setting it in your function here?

Comment: I also found that the recommended way to do this is to call `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of setting the CSS properties manually have you tried that? Also for showing a spinner I would use `div` since this is an element that should be displayed as a block while `span` is just `inline` by default.

Comment: @LarsVonk yes, I did tried that for testing purpose, and it works perfectly fine. But through Javascript it doesn't.

Comment: `But through Javascript it doesn't. ` -> why you are trying to mix javascript with above jquery code?

Comment: @LarsVonk I've updated the code while replacing the span with div and with .show() and .hide() still it's not working. Any more ideas please?

Comment: Hello, when I take the spinner div out of the button element then it's working. But not when it's inside the button?

Comment: that is very weird, can you also share the code you use to make the spinner? The javascript functionality seems fine and if it works outside of the button the problem shouldn't come from the code. Have you tried instead to change the display to `block` instead of `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

a) You need to put spinner outside of button

b) Add a class initially which has `dispaly:none` CSS applied on it.

c) Now use `.show()` and `.hide()` to work around it.

Working sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.submitSpinner').show();
    setTimeout(
      function() {
         $('.submitSpinner').hide();
      }, 5000);
   
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button class="btn btn-medium btn-fancy btn-primary mb-0 ls-wider" type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <span class="submitSpinner spinner-border spinner-border-sm me-1 hide">Send Message...</span>
</div>
```